# Basic SED question for Linux

Tags: sed

Temp file has only the number 22.5 in it.

I use

```
sed 's/.//' Temp
```

and I expect 225 but get 2.5

Why?

Answer (score 8):

The dot is a special character meaning "match any character".

```
$ sed s/\\.// temp
225
```

You would think that you could do `sed s/\.// temp`, but your shell will escape that single backslash and pass `s/.//` to sed..  So, you need to put two backslashes to pass a literal backslash to sed, which will properly treat `\.` as  a literal dot. Or, you could quote the command to retain the literal backslash:

```
$ sed "s/\.//" temp
225
```

The reason you get 2.5 when you do `s/.//` is that the dot matches the first character in the file and removes it.

Answer (score 3):

Because '.' is a regular expression that matches any character.  You want `'s/\.//'`

Answer (score 1):

`.` is a wildcard character for any character, so the first character is replaced by nothing, then sed is done.

You want `sed 's/\.//' Temp`.  The backslash is used to escape special characters so that they regain their face value.

Answer (score 0):

'.' is special: it matches any single character. So in your case, the sed expression matches the first character on the line. Try escaping it like this:

s/\.//

Comment: It doesn't look like you escaped it here.

Comment: Heh. Looks like the edit widget eats backslash. I needed to escape the escape to make it show up :)

Answer (score 0):

you can also use awk

```
awk '{sub(".","")}1' temp
```